Calculating Kd(490) and exporting indices like NDWI in DEA Sandbox
I'm a beginner in remote sensing, currently working on a class project where I’m comparing field data on inshore water quality (e.g., Secchi depth, turbidity) with satellite data products.
My goal is to assess the accuracy of different satellite products, such as those from Sentinel and Landsat, for understanding water quality parameters like clarity and turbidity in coastal areas that flow into the Great Barrier Reef.
I’ve been using Digital Earth Australia’s Sandbox, and I’m wondering:
How can I use the DEA Sandbox to calculate Kd(490) (the diffuse attenuation coefficient at 490 nm) on existing remote sensing data?

As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.

I suggest you begin by exploring the two notebooks linked below, they contain most of the info you need. Be warned though, there are multiple band indices called "NDWI" and they measure different things. Some of them try to identify water in the landscape, while others are designed for measuring canopy moisture content. And depending on the sensor, the bands used to calculate NDWI change as well, so be careful.
https://knowledge.dea.ga.gov.au/notebooks/How_to_guides/Calculating_band_indices/
https://knowledge.dea.ga.gov.au/notebooks/How_to_guides/Calculating_band_indices/
